# Rules about claiming a tunnel in Ticket to Ride Switzerland

Tags: ticket-to-ride

I just want to be clear about how to claim a short tunnel route in Ticket to Ride Switzerland.

Say I am taking a tunnel that requires only one card (red, for instance). If I turn over a red card I need another red card (or a locomotive) to match it. But if I turn over 2 further red cards (i.e. 3 red cards in all) do I need further red cards (or locomotives) to match?

It would seem strange to have to use 4 red cards in total to claim a one route.

Comment: Note that this mechanism is an attempt to reflect the uncertain and treacherous nature of tunneling through mountains. Even short tunnels can be extremely expensive and fatal to build, often with massive delays, which is reflected in your scenario above.

Comment: And you always can resign building tunnel if it was too hard and loose move.

Answer (score 8):

You must have an additional Train Car card of the appropriate color (or a locomotive) for each card of that color that gets flipped over.

From the [Ticket to Ride: Switzerland](https://cdn0.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/img/tt_switzerland_rules.pdf) rules (emphasis added):

> When attempting to claim a Tunnel route, a player first lays down the number of cards required. Then the 3 top cards from the Train Car card draw pile are turned face-up. **For each card revealed** whose color matches the color used to claim the Tunnel (including locomotives), an additional card of the same color (or a locomotive) must be played to successfully claim the Tunnel.